# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck like process for non-normal data distributions

Tags: stochastic-processes

I have a set of data which histogram looks like this:

[image]

The values are not normally distributed since the distribution is not simetric.

For another set of data that is normally distributed, I have used a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck stochastic process to generate representative values.

Since OU processes only work with normally distributed data, what can I use to represent the depicted data set?

Thanks.

Comment: Ornstein, not Örnstein.

Comment: Changed, now, any answer?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Where does this histogram come from? What all this has to do with stochastic processes and with Ornstein-Uhlenbeck in particular?

Comment: The histogram represents the agregation of power plants generation forecast error. I want to be able to generate random meaningfull error series that follow that distribution instead of a normal distribution.

Comment: You've made even less clear. (By the way, you should add a nickname when responding to a comment, otherwise there's no notification.) There is a "process" in the title. Where is a process in your question?

Comment: I'm guessing you have some sort of a forecasting model and you're examining its errors. 

If the forecasts are generated separately and independently, then you shouldn't try to model the errors with a time series. You should simply fit a distribution to them - perhaps a composite normal or something.

Comment: Both errors are weakly dependent, that why using OU is appealing. But since one of the errors is not estrictly normal, I wonder if I can modify the OU random generator to use the empirical distribution instead of a normal distriution and still be correct.